# Best practices with monad transformers : to hide or not to hide 'liftIO'

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

*I will preface this by saying that I am a novice Haskell programmer (tinkered with it sporadically over the years) but I have a fair few years on the counter when it comes to OOO and imperative programming. I am currently learning how to use monads & combining them via the use of monad transformers (assuming I've got the correct term).*

---

While I am able to assemble/chain things together, I am finding it hard to build an intuition for what the best way and style is & how best to assemble/write those interactions.

Specifically, I am curious to know what the best practice (or at least your practice) is for using lift/liftIO and any flavour in between & if there is way (and benefit) to hide them as I am finding them rather 'noisy'.

Below is an example snippet which I have put together to illustrate what I mean :

```
consumeRenderStageGL' :: RenderStage -> StateT RenderStageContext IO ()
consumeRenderStageGL' r = do 
    pushDebugGroupGL (name r)
    liftIO $ consumePrologueGL ( prologue r )
    liftIO $ consumeEpilogueGL ( epilogue r )
    consumeStreamGL   ( stream   r )
    liftIO $ popDebugGroupGL
```

Some of the functions it calls make use of the state monad :

```
pushDebugGroupGL :: String -> StateT RenderStageContext IO ()
pushDebugGroupGL tag = do
    currentDebugMessageID <- gets debugMessageID
    liftIO $ GL.pushDebugGroup GL.DebugSourceApplication (GL.DebugMessageID currentDebugMessageID) tag
    modify (\fc -> fc { debugMessageID = (currentDebugMessageID + 1) })

consumeStreamGL :: Stream -> StateT RenderStageContext IO ()
consumeStreamGL s = do 
    mapM_ consumeTokenGL s
    logGLErrors
```

While most don't and just live in IO (meaning they have to be lifted):

```
consumePrologueGL :: Prologue -> IO ()
consumePrologueGL p = do
    colourClearFlag     <- setupAndReturnClearFlag GL.ColorBuffer   ( clearColour  p ) (\(Colour4 r g b a) -> GL.clearColor $= (GL.Color4 r g b a))
    depthClearFlag      <- setupAndReturnClearFlag GL.DepthBuffer   ( clearDepth   p ) (\d -> GL.clearDepthf $= d)
    stencilClearFlag    <- setupAndReturnClearFlag GL.StencilBuffer ( clearStencil p ) (\s -> GL.clearStencil $= fromIntegral s)
    GL.clear $ catMaybes [colourClearFlag, depthClearFlag, stencilClearFlag]
    logGLErrors
    where
        setupAndReturnClearFlag flag mValue function = case mValue of 
            Nothing     -> return Nothing
            Just value  -> (function value) >> return (Just flag)
```

My question is : **is there any way to hide the **liftIO** in **consumeRenderStageGL'** and more importantly would this be a good or a bad idea?**

One way I can think of hiding/getting rid of the liftIO is to bring both my **consumePrologueGL** & **consumeEpilogueGL** into my state monad but this seems wrong in the sense that those function do not need (and should not) interact with it ; all this just to reduce code noise.

The other option I can think of is to simply create the lifted version of the functions and call them in **consumeRenderStageGL'** - this would reduce the code noise but be identical in execution/evaluation.

The third option, which is how my **logGLErrors** works is that I have used a type class which has an instance defined for both IO & my state monads.

I look forward to reading what your opinions, advices and practices are.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The most obvious way to do it would be to push the `liftIO` down into `consumePrologueGL`, making it `consumePrologueGL :: MonadIO m => Prologue -> m ()`

Comment: Interesting, I had not considered that - would liftIO be 'free' if used directly in the IO monad then (in the sense of evaluation)?

Comment: Correct.  It's just the identity in that scenario.

Comment: I did read a few posts about the MonadIO vs IO 'teams', although I wasn't able to make my mind up whether writing every single function that does IO in MonadIO was considered overkill/overengineering (like trying to write a templated class in C++ for the sake of it when it only gets used in a very specific scope)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few solutions. A common one is to make your basic actions `MonadIO m => m …` instead of `IO …`:

```
consumePrologueGL :: (MonadIO m) => Prologue -> m ()
consumePrologueGL p = liftIO $ do
  …
```

Then you can use them in `StateT RenderStageContext IO ()` without wrapping, due to `MonadIO m => MonadIO (StateT s m)`, and of course `MonadIO IO` where `liftIO` is the identity function.

You can also abstract over the `StateT` part using `MonadState` from `mtl`, so if you add another transformer above/below it, you won’t have the same issue of lifting from/to `StateT`.

```
pushDebugGroupGL
  :: (MonadIO m, MonadState RenderStageContext m)
  => String -> m ()
```

Generally, a concrete stack of `transformers` types is *fine*, it just helps to wrap all your basic operations for convenience so that all the `lift`s are in one place.

`mtl` helps remove the `lift` noise from your code altogether, and working in a polymorphic type `m` means you have to declare which effects a function actually uses, and can substitute different implementations of all the effects (except for `MonadIO`) for testing. Using monad transformers as an effect system like this is great if you have few types of effects; if you want something finer-grained or more flexible, you’ll start hitting the pain points that make people reach for *algebraic effects* instead.

It’s also worth assessing whether you need `StateT` over `IO`. Typically if you’re in `IO`, you don’t need the pure state offered by `StateT`, so instead of `StateT MutableState IO` you might as well use `ReaderT (IORef MutableState) IO`.

It’s also possible to make that (or a `newtype` wrapper for it) an instance of `MonadState MutableState`, so your code using `get`/`put`/`modify` wouldn’t even need to change:

```
{-# Language GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Data.Coerce (coerce)

newtype MutT s m a = MutT
  { getMutT :: ReaderT (IORef s) m a }
  deriving
    ( Alternative
    , Applicative
    , Functor
    , Monad
    , MonadIO
    , MonadTrans
    )

evalMutT :: MutT s m a -> IORef s -> m a
evalMutT = coerce

instance (MonadIO m) => MonadState s (MutT s m) where
  state f = MutT $ do
    r <- ask
    liftIO $ do
      -- NB: possibly lazier than you want.
      (a, s) <- f <$> readIORef r
      a <$ writeIORef r s
```

This combo of `ReaderT` & `IO` is a pretty common design pattern.

Comment: Note that if part of what you're doing in `IO` (or `ST s`) involves extremely frequent state mutation (e.g., as part of a mutable array algorithm), then the overhead of `IORef` or `STRef` could become substantial, and `StateT` will be the right approach.

Comment: Thanks for the indepth answer. So it looks like taking my functions into MonadIO instead of IO is the simplest/quickest solution given my functions are not meant to be exported/exposed. I'll definitely need to put your newtype / ReaderT & IO combo a try at some point though as it sounds interesting & useful.